# youtube cms performance report download api

Tags: youtube-api

We have a manual process to download the performance report from youtube cms application. This report is a csv or zip that is generated weekly and gives the "view" details for every video owned by the user at a daily level.

Is there an API to download this report ? I looked at the youtube analytics api and it looks like I have to get the data for each video individually. We have a lot of videos and this will be over the quota. Is there a way to get the weekly performance report through some api ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current YouTube Analytics API isn't well suited for performing bulk reporting for any significant volume of videos.

There's an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=4057) that you can "Star" to be notified when there's an alternative approach available. I'm afraid that I don't have any timelines to share, but it's being actively worked on.

Comment: thanks, is there a way to get all videos uploaded by a user, in my case there are about 13,000 videos for the user. I tried the sample code that gets the items by playlist (https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list), however it doesnt return any video because my default channel does not have a playlist.

Comment: The way to get all the videos for a given channel is to first authenticate as the channel, and then get the id of the uploads playlist (every channel with videos has an uploads playlist, even if it doesn't have any "real" playlists), and then get the contents of that uploads playlist. An example in Python is at https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#my_uploads

Answer (score 1):

As Jeff pointed out before, you won't be able to download a performance report from Youtube CMS using Youtube Analytics API.

You can use mechanize module in python to log in to your youtube cms account and navigate to that download URL.

```
browser = mechanize.Browser()
browser.open('http://cms.youtube.com')
browser.select_form(nr = 0)
browser.form['Email'] = email
browser.form['Passwd'] = password
browser.submit()
browser.open(dashboard_url) //url that you get redirected to when you login
```

and then you can search for reports link. then click on that. then search for the report you want and download it.

more info here:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet/

i was able to download reports that i want using this module in python.